# Magento 2: Update Cart "Invalid Address Id"

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, address

When i try to update card from my account. It says below error message.

[image]

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7570

Due to that my DHL International Shipping is not showing Shipping rates.